# JAVA Storing 3 or more classes in array

Tags: java, arrays, class, abstract-class

I'm a little stuck and would definitely appreciate your help. As the title says I want to store different classes on an array, which is in another class
This would be my code

The Customer class:

```
public class Customer {
public List<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();
public void addProduct(Product p){
    products.add(p);
}
```

}

The Product class:

```
public abstract class Product{ }
```

The Ham class:

```
public class Jamon extends Product{ 
protected String marca;
protected int precio;

public Jamon(String marca,Double precio){
    this.marca=marca;
    this.precio=precio;
}

public void setMarca(String marca){
    this.marca=marca;
}
public String getMarca(){
    return marca;
}

public void setPrecio(int precio){
    this.precio=precio;
}
public int getPrecio(){
    return precio;
}
*/

public void comprar(){
    System.out.println("Se ha comprado el jamon");
}
```

What I want to know is How do i store the Jamon class in the array on the Customer class, i want this because there will be multiple classes like Jamon that extend from Product. Also, if all this classes (Pepino, Jelly, etc) have precios, how can I add all the precios?
Thank you, if you have any doubt about my question please ask me (english is not my first language) Nice Day (:

Comment: Can you share what's going wrong, such as error messages?  Your theory is right: because Jamon (Ham?) extends Product, the Customer's ArrayList<Product> can store instances of Jamon (or anything else that's a Product).

Comment: You can put all the sub types in an array of a type. Are you facing any issue while trying to add `Jamon` to your arry?

Comment: If you have an array of type Product, any class that inherits from Product can be placed into a Product array.

Comment: Pick the closest common superclass of the various classes you will store in the array and make the array that type.  In this case the common superclass appears to be Product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a small implementation of what you appear to be trying to achieve

```
public abstract class Product {
    protected double precio;

    public void setPrecio(double precio){
        this.precio=precio;
    }

    public double getPrecio(){
        return precio;
    }
}
```

Here's another one

```
public class Jamon extends Product{ 
    protected String marca;

    public Jamon(String marca,Double precio){
        this.marca=marca;
        this.precio=precio;
    }

    public void setMarca(String marca){
        this.marca=marca;
    }

    public String getMarca(){
        return marca;
    }   

    public void comprar(){
        System.out.println("Se ha comprado el jamon");
    }
}
```

Here's also this one

```
public class Pepino extends Product{ 
    protected String marca;

    public Pepino(String marca,Double precio){
        this.marca=marca;
        this.precio=precio;
    }

    public void setMarca(String marca){
        this.marca=marca;
    }

    public String getMarca(){
        return marca;
    }   

    public void comprar(){
        System.out.println("Se ha comprado el pepino");
    }
}
```

And finally

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Customer {
    public List<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();

    public void addProduct(Product p){
        products.add(p);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        Jamon jamon = new Jamon("Jabugo", 25.0);
        Pepino pepino = new Pepino("Extra picante", 8.50);
        Jamon negro = new Jamon("Pata Negra", 32.99);
        customer.addProduct(jamon);
        customer.addProduct(pepino);
        customer.addProduct(negro);
        for (Product product : customer.products) {
            System.out.println(product.getClass());
        }
    }
}
```

Okay, so to be clear. Both Jamon and Pepino extend from Product, which means:

-Any variable (such as precio) or method (setPrecio or getPrecio) is available to them. Since its defined in the abstract class. One exception to this are the ones with **private**, those won't be accesible in the extending classes.

-Since customer adds a bunch of elements as Product there is no way to access the methods defined in Jamon or Pepino unless the item in the list is casted.

-It is not very common practice to declare an inner field a public variable (I'm referring to products in Customer, make a getter/setter).

-Also in your small example you seem to mix the ideas of **double** and **int** both represent numbers, but only the first has decimal point. If you are using decimal values, as it happens with precio, declare the field a **double** and work always with a double.

New Customer class (only storing prices, as oposed to Product, in the ArrayList)

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Customer {
    public List<Double> products = new ArrayList<Double>();

    public void addProduct(Product p){
        products.add(p.getPrecio());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        Jamon jamon = new Jamon("Jabugo", 25.0);
        Pepino pepino = new Pepino("Extra picante", 8.50);
        Jamon negro = new Jamon("Pata Negra", 32.99);
        customer.addProduct(jamon);
        customer.addProduct(pepino);
        customer.addProduct(negro);
        for (Double productPrice : customer.products) {
            System.out.println(productPrice);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi! thank you so much for your help, I had written it almost like you except I included precio in each extend class of Product and not directly in Product, but it is so much better if you include it in Product directly. i only have one more question, please. Suppose I only want an Array of precios, I mean, I want and array that contains all of Jamon, Pepino, etc precios, how can I do it? Thanks (:

Comment: Well, the comment section isn't probably long enough for me to describe another full solution. Based on what you are saying, it seems you need to change your ArrayList to:
`public List<Double> products = new ArrayList<Double> ()`
And then, instead of adding a Product you add it's price:
`products.add(p.getPrecio())`

Comment: to what? I'm sorry but your answer only appears at change  your ArrayList to: Do you want me to ask another question?

Comment: I edited both my comment and my answer. I hope it's what you were going for.

Answer (score 0):

As others have already commented, you can add an instance of any subclass of `Product` to an `ArrayList<Product>`.  That you have done already.

If you want all products to have a `precio`, then you can define it on the abstract class `Product` instead of in `Jamon` and other subclasses.  Move the declaration of the variable `precio` from `Jamon` to `Product`.  Also move the methods `getPrecio` and `setPrecio` to `Product`.  Create a constructor in `Product` to accept a `precio`.  In constructors of subclasses such as `Jamon`, call `super(precio)` to initialize `precio`.

Then, you will be able to loop over all `Product`s in your `ArrayList` and call the `getPrecio()` method to add up all `precio`s.